# Easy way to change one field in struct?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Point {
    x: f64,
    y: f64,
    z: f64
}

impl Point {
    fn set_z(&self, val: f64) -> Point {
        Point{x: self.x, y: self.y, z: val}
    }
}

struct Boo {
    point: Point
}

impl Boo {
    fn point(&self) -> &Point { &self.point }
    fn set_point(&mut self, val: &Point) { self.point = *val; }
}

fn main() {
    let mut boo = Boo{point:Point{x: 0., y: 0., z: 0.}};
    let new_p = boo.point().set_z(17.);
    boo.set_point(&new_p);
}
```

In fact, I have bunch of structures like `Boo` with `Point` fields, and often enough I need to change only one field in it.

So I can

1. Implement millions of methods like:

   ```
   impl Boo {
       fn set_x(&mut self, val: f64) { self.point.x = val; }
       fn set_y(&mut self, val: f64) { self.point.y = val; }
       //...
   }
   ```

   Which is too boring, and if have two, three fields like `point1`, `point2` and so on I will be buried under tons of these methods.
2. The method described at the top of the question looks nicer because I need only two methods per field, but I have to make modification in two steps: get point and set point.

So the ideal method for me would look like this:

```
boo.set_point(boo.point().set_z(17.));
```

But this is impossible, because to implement this I need to somehow read and write references at the same time.

How can I simplify setting only one field of `Point` for users of my module?

Comment: It feels that if you have so many types that need to do the same thing, then you actually have one type that should have many instances.

Comment: You can change your impl Point like this: ```impl Point {
        fn set_z(&self, val: f64) -> Point {
            Point{z: val, *self}
        }
    ```

Comment: In topic, I think you could write own `derive` that will implement `set_x`, `set_z` functions in `Boo` for you. But I am just a begginer and can't help you with example.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you make those fields public?

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
struct Point {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64
}

struct Boo {
    pub point: Point
}

boo.point.z = 17.0;
```

Encapsulation is a good thing and you often don't want everyone to change the internal fields of a type. But this is only necessary if there are illegal values the field mustn't take on *or* if other values are dependent on that field (e.g. caches). But if that's not the case -- and in your example it doesn't look like it is -- then just mark those fields as public.

Comment: You can also make `point` public but not `z`, then you could call `boo.point.set_z(17.0)`.

Comment: Is there a way to keep x,y,z private but allow the creating a copy with x different?